# Simple Geographic Data Sources for a Web App

Tags: geolocation, geography

For a web app I'm working on, I need to know the lat/lon of about 300 US cities.  I also need to know the lat/lon for every US zip code.

Does anyone know of a free source to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Freebase](http://freebase.com) will likely be able to help you.  [Here is New York](http://www.freebase.com/view/guid/9202a8c04000641f80000000002f8906) and it has Lat/Long.

The [Wal-Mart Expansion video](http://blog.kiwitobes.com/?p=51) used Freebase to get it's data, and it sounds like you're doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ben Fry's [Zip Code Visualizer](http://benfry.com/zipdecode/). This is part of his book [Visualizing Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514557).

Answer (score 1):

There is an online database at [Geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/).   And a [simple perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~sderle/Geo-Coder-US/US.pm) (we added a soap service to this so we could simply access it from any language, and the longest part of the development process was downloading database (it's about 4 GB).)  The geocoing database is available from the US census bureau, a good article on getting this setup can be found [here](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/3557171).